# Error when running LDA on Tweets using gensim in Python

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I have the following code, to run an LDA analysis on Tweets:

```
import logging, gensim, bz2
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

# load id->word mapping (the dictionary), one of the results of step 2 above
id2word = 'enams4nieuw.dict'
# load corpus iterator
mm = gensim.corpora.MmCorpus('enams4nieuw.mm')

print(mm)

# extract 100 LDA topics, using 1 pass and updating once every 1 chunk (10,000 documents)
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=mm, id2word=id2word, num_topics=100, update_every=1, chunksize=10000, passes=1)
```

When I try to run this script, I receive the following log with error message:

```
MmCorpus(40152 documents, 13061 features, 384671 non-zero entries)
2015-03-31 16:52:50,246 : INFO : loaded corpus index from enams4nieuw.mm.index
2015-03-31 16:52:50,246 : INFO : initializing corpus reader from enams4nieuw.mm
2015-03-31 16:52:50,246 : INFO : accepted corpus with 40152 documents, 13061 features, 384671 non-zero entries
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gerbuiker/PycharmProjects/twitter-streaming.py/lda.py", line 15, in <module>
    lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=mm, id2word=id2word, num_topics=100, update_every=1, chunksize=10000, passes=1)
  File "C:\Users\gerbuiker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 244, in __init__
self.num_terms = 1 + max(self.id2word.keys())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You set the variable id2word as a string.

It appears that you have a filename -- I'm assuming you pickled your dictionary?

id2word needs to be a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it seemed like ldamodel.py was trying to take the max value of the keywords rather than the indexes/ID's so my solution was simply to swap the columns in the dict.

```
my_dict2 = {y:x for x,y in my_dict.items()}
```